# como pudiera poner una variable tipo int al generar un archivo txt en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, filewriter

al generar un archivo *txt*, quisiera poner el resultado de una variable en el archivo pero me aparece este error:

```
write() argument must be str, not int
```

y también este

```
'_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'writes'
```

Quisiera saber si hay una manera de escribir la variable numérica.

```
    valor = 57

def crear ():
    file = open("C:/Users/heaky/Documents/programacion/papa/lologramos.txt", "w")
    file.writes(valor)
    file.close()
    print ("exito")
crear()
```

Comment: Lo primero, un error tipográfico, el método se llama `write`, no `writes`, por otro lado como indica el error, debes hacer un casting a `str` de forma explícita: `file.write(str(valor))`. Estás escribiendo en un archivo de texto, luego debes proporcionar una cadena, Python jamas hace un casting implícito.

Comment: @FJSevilla, debes escribir eso como una respuesta. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar, el método que usas **writes** no existe, debería de ser **write**

Para poder concatenar cadenas **string** y números enteros **int** debes de hacer un parse de **int** -> **string**. Para ello puedes usar:

- La función **str(numero)**

  ```
  file.write(str(valor))
  ```
- Hacer un **format**

  ```
  file.write("%d" % (valor))
  ```
- O bien

  ```
  file.write("{}".format(valor))
  ```
- Tambien tenemos la opcion en Python >= 3.6 los literales de cadena formateados

  ```
  file.write(f"{valor}")
  ```

En tu caso la opción más sencilla y la más clara es la primera, pero si tubieras que pasar múltiples números enteros, las otras dos serían más prácticas

Comment: Hola gmarsi, `"%d".format(value)` no es una forma válida de formatear cadenas en Python, creo que te refieres a  `"%d" % valor`. Por cierto, si quieres añadirlo, en Python >= 3.6 tenemos los literales de cadena formateados, `file.write(f"{valor}")`. Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, FJSevilla. Corregido y añadido a la respuesta. :D